# What is the meaning of すべてはじまりそれが答えだろ

Tags: translation, song-lyrics

> 夢見るコトが
> すべてはじまり　それが答えだろ
> 　誰より遠くへ飛んで見せるよ
> すべての明日を貫いて

This is a passage of the the song "The Biggest Dreamer" which is the opening of digimon tamers.

I would like to know the meaning of that すべてはじまり. Is it missing a の? Is it a casual way of saying すべてのはじまり？ I believe it means "Dreaming is the start of everything" but why isn't there a の？

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it missing a の? Is it a casual way of saying すべてのはじまり?

No, you usually cannot omit の at this position if "start of everything" is the intended meaning. So you should first see if this すべて is working adverbially. Just as "これはすべて本だ" means "These are *all* books", "夢見るコトがすべてはじまり(だ)" could mean "(Actions of) dreaming are *all* beginnings", or a little more naturally, "Dreaming is *always* the start (of something)".

(I said "usually" because this is a part of lyrics; if the adverbial reading fails, we may have to accept the adjectival reading even though it's incorrect in prose. But the adverbial reading seems to fit the context in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

First I agree with "Dreaming is the start of everything". And yes すべてのはじまり or something のはじまりis often used as "beginning of sth". I sometimes see not using の when indicating affiliation, if that doesn't change the meaning.

I think a main reason is the rhythm (I may not use the words accurately, you can feel the difference by adding a preposition). すべてはじまり can treated as one item here "everything beginning", a missing of の does not affect the understanding "beginning of everything".